# passing parameters to functions that are attached to a jQuery UI Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery-UI dialog boxes and I have a rather complicated situation.

I have attached a function call to the "Save" button for my dialog, but I need to pass in dynamic parameters to that function.

The parameters I need to pass in are an "id" of a textbox element and two variables: "copyNum" which is just an integer and "original" which is 0 or 1. These values are all in the div that the dialog box opens.

So a complete call might look like this:

```
 AddYourAuthors(39842871, 5, 0);
```

I figured out how to call the function without parameters as shown below.

But I can't figure out how to get the 3 parameters in there because they will all be dynamic.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
$("#AuthorByBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
       {
          id: "SaveAuthors",
          text: "Save",
          click: function () {
               //how do I pass parameters to this function call dynamically?
               AddYourAuthors();
       }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... use `find` to get the divs.

```
    click: function() {
        var dlg = $("#AuthorByBox");
        var id = dlg.find("#id").text();
        var copyNum = dlg.find("#copyNum").text();
        var orig = dlg.find("#original").text();
        AddYourAuthors(id, copyNum, orig);
    }
```